# How to calculate StartDate and EndDate based on ReportingMonth value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Need to calculate StartDate and EndDate based on ReportingMonth value

sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TestDate (
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [PerID] [int] NULL,
    [CommID] [int] NULL,
    [ReportingMonth] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Number] [nvarchar](200) NULL
)

Insert into TestDate ( [ID],[PerID],[CommID],[ReportingMonth],[Number])
    Values ('3820','12508','7','Jul-16','31');
Insert into TestDate ( [ID],[PerID],[CommID],[ReportingMonth],[Number])
    Values ('10235','12498','58','Aug-16','1');
Insert into TestDate ( [ID],[PerID],[CommID],[ReportingMonth],[Number])
    Values ('10235','12498','2','Jul-16','15');
```

I need to calculate StartDate and EndDate based on ReportingMonth with the difference of Number column

Expected output for **StartDate and EndDate** should be like this

```
ID  PerID   CommID  ReportingMonth  StartDate   Number  EndDate
3820    12508   7   Jul-16          30/06/2016  31      31/07/2016
10235   12498   58  Aug-16          15/07/2016  1       1/08/2016
10235   12498   2   Jul-16          15/07/2016  15      1/08/2016
```

SQL Query that I used to calculate start date for one month is working but when there are more than one same ID then it is not working

```
select [ID]
       ,[PerID]
       ,[CommID]
       ,[ReportingMonth]
       ,[Number]
       ,DATEADD(DAY, -(cast([Number] as int)), eomonth(CAST([Number] as DateTime)))  as StartDate
    from TestDate
```

How to get StartDate and EndDate base on just having only ReportingMonth field

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is pretty good about figuring out month conversions.  So, this should work:

```
select cast('01-' + ReportingMonth as date) as month_start,
       eomonth(cast('01-' + ReportingMonth as date)) as month_end
```

Comment: I need to calculate StartDate and Enddate based on [ReportingMonth]  and difference of [Number].      You can see the expected output in the original thread.